# the blue div came out oval

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

MY teacher gave us the project to make the Laos flag using CSS. she wrote the HTML for us but we can not change/add anything.
this is the HTML

```html
<body>
<div class="flag">
<p>The Flag</p>
<div>
<div>
<p>of Laos</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

this was the answer she gave, she told us if we did it another way (selectors) that was ok.

```css
.flag{
width: 900px;
height: 600px;
background-color: #CE1126; (this is red)
position: relative;

    }

.flag > div{
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background-color: #002868; (this is blue
position: absolute;
top: 150px;
    }

.flag > div > div{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: 50px;
left: 350px;
    }
    

p{
margin: 0;
font-size: 5rem;
text-align: center;
color: white;
    }

div div p{color: black;}
```

I could not finish so I just watch how she did the parts that I didn't know

```css
.flag{
 width: 900px;
height: 600px;
background-color: #CE1126; (this is red)
position: relative;

 }

.flag > div{
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background-color: #002868;  (this is blue)
border-radius: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 100px;
left: 0px;
    }

div div{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 20%;
left: 300px;
}
```

for some reason the blue box came out as an oval the only way to make it a rectangle was to make the `border-radius: 0px;` but that not in her answer. the text part I had right but I needed to make the text bigger and make the `margins 0`

[this is what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jau4.png)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting these issues, e.g. the blue rectangle being an oval, is because your CSS selector is too broad: `div div` means target any `div` element, that is a descendant (e.g. child, grandchild etc.) of another `div`. There are two such elements that satisfy this condition in your HTML, the middle one (as it has a parent `div`), and the innermost one (as it also has a parent `div`). Therefore by applying the `border-radius: 50%` to any element that satisfies the `div div` selector, you are applying a rounded border to both the innermost and middle `div`s.

The reason adding `border-radius: 0px` to the ruleset under the `.flag > div` selector fixes this issue, is that `.flag > div` is more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `div div`, hence the `border-radius: 0px` takes precedence when deciding what border your innermost div should have.

To fix this issue, in practice, you would add specific classes to each part of the flag to make them easier to target, but I understand that this assignment requires you to play around with CSS selectors. As such, you would need to choose a CSS selector that is unique to each part of the flag (unless you wish to share certain styles across many parts). Your teacher's example of the `.flag > div > div` selector targets only the innermost `div`, hence only the circle part of the flag.

Comment: Did you generate this using ChatGPT?

Comment: I did not use ChatGPT. I wrote the entire answer myself.

Comment: I'm curious what it was about this answer that made people suspect Chat GPT? 

dont get me wrong, I suspect the same thing on probably half the answers I see posted on this site, but for this particular one, it never crossed my mind - i dont recognize any of the tell-tale delivery styles/structure that the model is prone to using.

Comment: ok thank you I thought  'div div' would only target the grandchild, I also didn't know it was possible to have more then one ">".  do you know how many ">" is possible to have when selecting. I know it would be shorter to just have an ID/class but I'm just curious

Comment: I'm not aware of there being a limit to the number of ">" you can have when selecting. It could be something very large, and sufficient for all practical purposes.